# Strange FTP issues - some files are not downloaded

Tags: centos, ftp

I have a machine, which cannot fetch some files from remote servers by FTP. Machine is powered by CentOS. I tested FTP on three files:

```
12.09.2012  21:21           166 007 ll091212.002
13.09.2012  11:32            23 040 ll091212.003
13.09.2012  11:50            61 313 ll091212.004
```

From them, I can always successfully download only one - ll091212.004. Two others are downloaded by about 90% (I can see them on disk) and then FTP transfer hangs without any error messages.

I move files, copy them about the remote server - no luck. Another machine from the same subnet can download all three of them easily.

I just don't know what's the reason of this.

Comment: double check if the disk is full, or any software like anti-virus stops it from completing the downloads.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check your firewall and look for ip-based traffic limitations